# What is the meaning of Range[10] /. {x_ /; PrimeQ[x] -> x^2}?

Tags: syntax, core-language

I'm currently doing a unit at university that touched briefly on *Mathematica*, but the final exam will feature multiple choice questions from *Mathematica* (along with excel and matlab). This leads to this question

```
Range[10] /. {x_ /; PrimeQ[x] -> x^2}
```

What does this actually do? I plugged it into *Mathematica*, and it gave me

> ```
> {1, 4, 9, 4, 25, 6, 49, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

as its output.

I lack the understanding of what each part of the input does as I never came across this earlier in my studies.

Comment: By `x2`, you really meant to say `x^2`, yes? Then all you're doing is replace any number that is prime with its square.

Comment: Based on the output shown in OP I've edited the OP to have `x^2`.

Comment: This could also be written `Range[10] /. {x_?PrimeQ -> x^2}`

Comment: I really don't see any reason to close this. It's not due to a 'simple mistake'; there is no mistake. Nor is an explanation of the OP expression 'easily found in the documentation'; it can found there, but not easily. There are two good, up-voted answers that are useful to future visitors. This question should be reopened.

Comment: @m_goldberg The answers are very useful for the OP (I upvoted both), but otherwise it is a localized question. What to do with any upcoming code snippets  a user wants reverse-engineered or explained in detail? I would not agree that searching is difficult here.

Comment: @m_goldberg While the entire structure is not "easily found in the documentation" it is nevertheless a rather basic operation that is covered in myriad other Q&A's on this site.  We have typically not been highly receptive to "explain this code for me" posts unless there was something unusual exhibited, if I am not mistaken.  How about marking this as a duplicate of [(25616)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121)?

Comment: @YvesKlett Please see my comment directly above.

Answer (score 6):

**`Range[10]`** - Make a list of integers from 1 to 10.

**`/.`** - Replace all occurrences of

**`{x_`** - anything, to which we will refer to as `x`

**`/;`** - so long as the test

**`PrimeQ[x]`** - for primality yields `True`

**`->`** - with

**`x^2}`** - the square of itself.

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of syntactic sugar in there. I'd like to add an answer to show you how you can make progress yourself when encountering unknown syntax.

If you wrap the code in `FullForm[Hold[...]]` Mathematica will show you the functions all these operators stand for:

```
FullForm[Hold[Range[10] /. {x_ /; PrimeQ[x] -> x^2}]]
(* Hold[ReplaceAll[Range[10], List[Rule[Condition[Pattern[x, Blank[]], PrimeQ[x]], Power[x, 2]]]]] *)
```

If you place your cursor in any of the unknown functions and hit <kbd>F1</kbd>, the docs will show you the details about these functions and also which operators are available for these. By matching the full form with the short form, we can figure some things out:

- `x /. y` is short for [`ReplaceAll[x, y]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html).
- `x_` is a [`Blank[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) named `x` which matches any one value.
- `/;` denotes a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) qualifying the pattern more precisely.
- `a -> b` is a [`Rule[a, b]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) which specifies what to replace with what.
- `x^y` is [`Power[x,y]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html).

From this, we hopefully piece things together: the code create a range from `1` to `10` and then replaces every prime with its square.